Help identify 80s Sci-Fi show
I was a little kid then, this is what I remember:
It was an early 80's Sci-Fi show, I watched it around 1985 I think. The main villains were a family of Aliens, who looked like humans. They drove an old Rolls-Royce, lived in a villa. The main protagonists, who were kids I think, tried to prove all the time those people are Aliens. I remember they broke into their house, swam in some water, there were eggs and cocoons and stuff. The last episode ended with people shooting lasers at those aliens and they all turned into small piles of soil like mole heaps.
Can anybody remember this series?

Was it "The Third Eye"? I watched a LOT of television in the 80's...based on your question, that's the show that comes to mind.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Eye_%28TV_series%29

Wow thanks, it was The Third Eye - Under The Mountain. Thanks very much! I saw it on YT, and it looks different now than 30 years ago obviously, but I remember that car and some scenes and the ending. It is this series, thanks again!
